# How to setup Customer profile manager, so user has possibility to select their existing billing address?

Tags: entities, commerce, users

I have entity form to which I've added *Customer profile reference* (`commerce_customer.module`) which has the reference to user's [Customer Profile](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/configuring-creating-customer-profiles) - *Billing information* (which by default consist *Postal address*).

However it is always showing blank postal address fields to enter new Postal address without possibility of using/selecting the existing one.

Is there any way that I can configure *Customer profile manager* widget so user can select his address from already existing one (by choosing either from the list or entering a new one)?

Comment: IIRC, the ability to have it be selectable via dropdown is a function of the checkout form, not the field.

Comment: Correct. I think we have a pending issue in the queue to add support for address selection via the customer profile manager widget. Same may also go for inline entity forms.

Comment: @RyanSzrama Thanks for reply. It's possible that you can post the link to the feature issue?